# Resize Svg Image Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am working on a PHP script which contains a page that has SVG inside it. What I want to do is to use the Jquery Resize feature. I have tried this on a div and it's working fine but when I want to use it to resize the image inside the SVG it doesn't work.
Here is the code:

doiud

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="420" id="svg">
<image height="120" width="120" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://designpieces.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/chrome.png" ></image></svg>
```

The Jquery Code :

```
$('.resize').resizable({
    ghost: true
            });
            $('image').resizable({
    ghost: true
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nCAkM/39/

Comment: You can try to put the SVG into some DIV, set width & height of SVG to "100%" and make the DIV resizable.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nCAkM/40/)

Wrapped on div to image.

html

```
<div class="resize">
resize helper
</div>


<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="420" id="svg">
    <image height="120" width="120" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://designpieces.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/chrome.png" ></image>
</svg>
```

script

```
$('.resize').resizable({
    ghost: true,
    resize: function( event, ui ) {
        var width = ui.size.width;
      var height = ui.size.height;
      $('image').attr('width',width);
      $('image').attr('height',height);
    }
            });

var position = $('svg').position();
$('.resize').css('top',position.top);
$('.resize').css('left',position.left);
```

css

```
.resize{
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
}
```

Comment: how about making this to multiple images in the svg it is possible ?

Comment: could you please add rotate option too.

Comment: @Felix i can't add rotate use only JqueryUI. but i found [jquery-ui-rotatable](https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable/)
and..this is [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/nCAkM/78/). i think this is not perfect.
you have to calculate degrees and transform position.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips. I was able to wrap my svg object within a div. And then I used the resize ui event size to set the CSS on the object.

HTML

```
  <div id="divVirtualKeyboard" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 100px">
    <div>
      <object id="canvasKeyboard" data="static/EmulatorKeyboard.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="376" height="214" style="pointer-events:none;"></object>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
  div.resizable(
    {
      aspectRatio: 376 / 214,
      resize: function (event, ui) {
        div.find('object').css('width', ui.size.width)
        div.find('object').css('height', ui.size.height)
      }
    });
```